# QFileDialog problem (native: fast but no input field; non-native: has input field but slow)

Tags: pyqt, qfiledialog

This seems a known problem but I have not found a good workaround. I like the style of the
non-native QFileDialog, especially the feature that allows the user to input the path directly
which is very convenient since the user can easily copy/paste the folder/file name from other applications. However, it seems very slow when the dialog is first launched. The native option
is quite responsive but the problem is that it does not provide an input field so for the user to select a folder he/she has to walk into the directory, which can take many mouse clicks and is not fun. I am not sure if you have experienced similar problem or if I miss something.

BTW, my PyQt version is 4.4.3 and I am working on Windows XP.

Thanks,
Bing

Comment: Which of the many QFileDialog? Which operating system? I can't understand very well which feature you are missing from native dialogs...

Comment: http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2010-December/028850.html

Comment: @Giovanni:  The feature I am missing from native dialogs is an input box that allows user to copy/paste folder names.